# Open Filechooser after Permission Granted in Android

Tags: java, android, android-webview, webchromeclient

I am using the following code to check if camera & storage permissions have been granted when user clicks on input-file field on my website in android webview:

```
 public boolean file_permission(){
         if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23 && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);

            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

  class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

            // Handling onshow file chooser
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

                if(file_permission() && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {

                    file_path = filePathCallback;
                    Intent takePictureIntent = null;

                        takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                            File photoFile = null;
                            try {
                                photoFile = create_image();
                                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", cam_file_data);
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                            }
                            if (photoFile != null) {
                                cam_file_data = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                            } else {
                                cam_file_data = null;
                                takePictureIntent = null;
                            }
                        }

                    Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    contentSelectionIntent.setType(file_type);

                    Intent[] intentArray;

                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};

                    Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Select Photo for yourPrint");
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, file_req_code);
                    return true;

                }  else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

When the permission is checked via `file_permission()`, the accept permission dialog appears. But once the user accepts the permission, the input-file field needs to be clicked again by the user to show the file chooser. I want the input-field that originally triggered the `onShowFileChooser` to be clicked again automatically after user accepts the permissions, so that file chooser opens automatically.

I have tried using `onRequestPermissionsResult` with javascript to trigger click on input field after permissions acceptance using this code `javascript:jQuery('.file-input-field').trigger('click')`, However, I do not want to use this way as chrome blocks programmatic clicks on input fields with type file for security purposes.

How to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you must reset this variable like this in java/kotlin :

```
filePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null)
filePathCallback = null
```

if filePathCallback not null onShowFileChooser will not triggered

Comment: Not correct at all, this is not opening the chooser after allowing the permission